# How to override seealso:: directive in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx in a project and I wanna change **'See also'** title in top of the `seealso::`'s box in the template.
I also searched a little in the codes and saw the SeeAlso class in the Sphinx library but I have no idea how to override it and change the title.

Comment: I would use the admonition [`admonition`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#directives) and supply my custom title.

Comment: @StevePiercy how u do that?

Comment: The Sphinx docs refers to the docutils docs, which in turn shows usage. See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#admonitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found a way that I think is the simple one!

My question was to be able to change the title of sphinx specific admonitions like seealso::

In the locale folder `(sphinx/locale/__init__.py)` , there is a dictionary named `admonitionlabels`, that the titles are defined here.

To change it in the project, we just add this code in the project's config.py:

```
from sphinx import locale
locale.admonitionlabels['seealso'] = 'new title'
```

and when we use `make html` sphinx will apply our new title to the project

Comment: This is neat, but it has one serious drawback: if later other people want to use your reST they won't know what the `.. seealso::` directive is.